# What is the PHP equivalent of this JS encrypter code?

Tags: javascript, php, openssl, steam, phpseclib

I am trying to log in to Steam (not via the API as it's very limited) with cURL, however I got stuck at encrypting the password.

Basically the process of logging in is posting a username to https://store.steampowered.com/login/getrsakey

The response looks like this:

```
{"success":true,"publickey_mod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publickey_exp":"010001","timestamp":"104490300000","token_gid":"3b54a605fa590d2"}
```

Then using this response, the javascript code encrypts the password.

I tried to use openssl and phpseclib, but no success. Openssl does not accept my key and with phpseclib I'm not sure what's the problem.

However I managed to find the JS code that takes care of this process:

```
var pubKey = RSA.getPublicKey( results.publickey_mod, results.publickey_exp );
var username = this.m_strUsernameCanonical;
var password = form.elements['password'].value;
password = password.replace( /[^\x00-\x7F]/g, '' ); // remove non-standard-ASCII characters
var encryptedPassword = RSA.encrypt( password, pubKey );
```

full code: https://steamstore-a.akamaihd.net/public/shared/javascript/login.js

So my final question is: How could I do this in PHP in the simpliest way?

Comment: 1. You would need to look at `getPublicKey` and `encrypt` from [**here**](https://steamstore-a.akamaihd.net/public/shared/javascript/crypto/rsa.js), 2. This is probably against the TOS, 3. I hope you're just doing it for yourself because if your server is logging in many people it looks like a good way to get their accounts suspended and your server's IP banned

Comment: I want to code a basic steam trade bot, not stealing accounts or things like that. I could not even do that because of SteamGuard (email/phone auth).

Comment: "How could I do this in PHP in the simpliest way?" --- the *simplest* way would be to hire someone, for sure. That way you don't need to waste your time and research/learn anything, I believe that's simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34399817/569976 . That said, I do believe this is the better post (even tho it's been downvoted more). In the last post a quick reading would lead one to conclude that the OP (you?) were trying to implement RSA encryption in JS on their website whereas with this post it is clear that you're not.

Comment: The Stack Overflow community amazes me at times. The fellow above asked a programming question and provided code, and he's been thoroughly belittled with down-votes. Yet 2 out of 3 off-topic OpenSSL questions can't even get 2 or 3 close votes (and are almost never down-voted even though they pollute the tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using phpseclib v1.0,

```
<?php
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://store.steampowered.com/login/getrsakey/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'donotcache' => time(),
    'username' => $username
));

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
$rsa->loadKey(array(
    'n' => new Math_BigInteger($result->publickey_mod, 16),
    'e' => new Math_BigInteger($result->publickey_exp, 16)
));

$password = base64_encode($rsa->encrypt($password));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://store.steampowered.com/login/dologin/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'donotcache' => time(),
    'password' => $password,
    'username' => $username,
    'twofactorcode' => '',
    'emailauth' => '',
    'loginfriendlyname' => '',
    'captchagid' => -1,
    'captcha_text' => '',
    'emailsteamid' => '',
    'rsatimestamp' => $result->timestamp,
    'remember_login' => false
));

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: @user3210615 - if you are truly thankful because neubert helped, then you should up-vote his answer. That's how Stack Overflow is supposed to work (but as you can see from the down votes, its far from ideal).